# Running and referencing a source generator library locally from a cloned repository

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, .net-core, nuget, sourcegenerators

I'm trying to experiment with a specific source generator library and I wanted to try and modify some parts of it. To do that cloned the repository for that library and referenced  two .csproj files in it from my own .NET 7 project. This looks at first like it would work, VS Code recognized the imports and doesn't complain, but the actual source generator part does not seem to work.

The specific library I'm using is [Mapperly](https://github.com/riok/mapperly) and I referenced it in my .csproj file as following:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\mapperly\src\Riok.Mapperly.Abstractions\Riok.Mapperly.Abstractions.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\mapperly\src\Riok.Mapperly\Riok.Mapperly.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

The error I get is

> Partial method 'MyMapper.MapToReadModel(MyEntity)' must have an implementation part because it has accessibility modifiers.

This code compiles if I add the complete nuget package of this library, and it stops working with this error if I remove the nuget package and reference the projects as I've shown. My understanding of this error would be that it indicated that the source generator either did not generate any source, or the build process doesn't use the generated source for some reason. The way this library works is that you define partial methods for mapping, and the source generator fills in the actual code, so that last step seems to fail in this case.

Obviously the way I'm referencing this library makes it behave differently than what happens when I add the full nuget package. The repository has more .csproj file, but those are all tests or samples. It also has a .sln file, but it seems I can't reference that directly.

I'm also using VS Code while the information I could find on this often assume Visual Studio, not sure if there are any limitations here with VS Code only.

What is the proper way to reference a local library that contains a source generator so that it will work properly in VS Code? Or am I misunderstanding the problem here and the cause is something else entirely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library you are referencing is not just regular library but a source generator, you need to reference them in a special way. You can see an example in [documentation for source generators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/source-generators-overview). Also note how authors of this library [reference](https://github.com/riok/mapperly/blob/main/test/Riok.Mapperly.IntegrationTests/Riok.Mapperly.IntegrationTests.csproj) their source generator project in their tests:

```
<!-- For local development, simply reference the projects. -->
  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(MapperlyNugetPackageVersion)' == ''">
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\src\Riok.Mapperly\Riok.Mapperly.csproj" OutputItemType="Analyzer" ReferenceOutputAssembly="false" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\src\Riok.Mapperly.Abstractions\Riok.Mapperly.Abstractions.csproj" OutputItemType="Analyzer" ReferenceOutputAssembly="true" />
  </ItemGroup>
```